# Replace flash-based charts with something that doesn't use flash

Tags: civireport

Several core reports (as well as some reports provided via extensions) use the OpenFlashChart library to create nice looking charts via flash.

Unfortunately (or fortunately depending on how you look at it), flash is on the way out. Many browsers disable it by default.

Has anyone worked on a drop-in replacement for Reports that use html5 or javascript or anything but flash? I know about Xavier's [CiviVisualize](https://github.com/TechToThePeople/civisualize) which looks very promising, but it's not clear how to use it in a report to replace the chart functionality provided by OpenFlashCharts.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is really answerable in it's current format. Your question seems to be "Has anyone worked on a drop-in replacement for Reports that use html5 or javascript or anything but flash?" What does an acceptable answer look like in your mind? This might be better placed as an issue on https://lab.civicrm.org

Comment: Thanks for following up. The answer might be "no, nobody has done anything like this." :). I'll try posting it on lab.civicrm.org and see what happens.

Comment: It’s always a risk to ask for someone to assert a negative :-) with that said - I’d be interested in seeing where this goes :-)

Answer (score 1):

As Lobo would say, "patch welcome."
I think everyone agrees the open flash chart library needs to be replaced, but that's about as far as it's gone to-date.